# zabuto calendar min and max date

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to add a **Zabuto Calendar** to my site.  Is there a way to set the min and max date, similar to how the jQuery Datepicker works?

For instance, with the jQuery datepicker you can set it to have a min and max date and any date not in between those two dates is grayed out and disabled.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date2);
```

I can't find any documentation for the **Zabuto Calendar** that would have similar functionality.

Is this able to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer is late, but I faced the problem and I didn't find a source in the web answering this question. Only add `show_next` attribute with the number of months to be shown in advance.

```
$("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
      action: function() { myDateFunction(); },
        show_previous: 1, // Will show 1 month back
        show_next: 3,     // Will show 3 months in advance
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the **[official website](https://github.com/zabuto/calendar#settings)**, you can [limit months navigation](http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/navigation_settings.html) with both `show_previous` and `show_next` parameters.

```js
// initialize the calendar on ready
$("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
  today: true,
  cell_border: true,
  weekstartson: 0,
  nav_icon: {
    prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
    next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
  },
  // limit months navigation to a specific range
  show_previous: 2,
  show_next: 2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zabuto_calendar/1.6.3/zabuto_calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zabuto_calendar/1.6.3/zabuto_calendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="my-calendar"></div>
```